# Apply class to 4 random images at the same time, then blur/fade one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to have this show 4 logos at the same time. Then I would like to only blur/fade one logo at a time and be replaced by another random logo.

Currently the code below shows only 1 logo at a time.

Here is a link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/james-anderson-the-encoder/pen/pxBQQj)

```js
setInterval(function(){
  var logoGrp = $('ul li').length;
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * logoGrp);
  $("ul li img").removeClass("unblur");
  $("ul li:nth-child(" + randomNum + ") img").addClass("unblur");
}, 4000);
```

```css
.content {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  li {
    position: absolute;
    &.client-1 {
      top: 55px;
      left: 45px;
    }
    &.client-2 {
      top: 0;
      left: 375px;
    }
    &.client-3 {
      top: 134px;
      left: 250px;
    }
    &.client-4 {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    &.client-5 {
      top: 100px;
      right: 276px;
    }
    &.client-6 {
      top: 182px;
      right: 45px;
    }
    &.client-7 {
      bottom: 175px;
      left: 0;
    }
    &.client-8 {
      bottom: 88px;
      left: 376px;
    }
     &.client-9 {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 123px;
    }
     &.client-10 {
      bottom: 170px;
      right: 233px;
    }
     &.client-11 {
      bottom: 89px;
      right: 0;
    }
     &.client-12 {
      bottom: 25px;
      right: 123px;
    }
  }
}


img { 
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transition: filter linear 1s, transform 1s, opacity 1s ;
  opacity: .25;
}

.unblur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: filter linear 1s, transform 3s, opacity 1s ;
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(100px); 
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<ul>
  <li class="client-1"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-2"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-3"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-4"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-5"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-6"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-7"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-8"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-9"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-10"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-11"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
  <li class="client-12"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png" ></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are pretty close to what you are after. If I understand correctly, you want to start with 4 images "unblurred", then, at each interval, you want to randomly blur one of the unblurred images and randomly unblur any image that is not already unblurred.

You can basically extend the logic you already have in your code and add the `unblur` class to 4 of your images to start with (you could add a little starter function to apply the `unblur` class randomly before your `setInterval` begins but I just manually added the `unblur` class to 4 images in the snippet below). Then, instead of selecting the entire group of images and applying your random blur / unblur to the whole group, you can select the blurred and unblurred groups separately and apply your random logic to each one to determine which of the respective groups get blurred / unblurred.

For example:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var unblurred = $('.unblur');
  var blurred = $('ul li img:not(.unblur)');
  var u = Math.floor(Math.random() * unblurred.length);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * blurred.length);
  $(unblurred[u]).removeClass('unblur');
  $(blurred[b]).addClass('unblur');
}, 4000);
```

```css
.content {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  li {
    position: absolute;
    &.client-1 {
      top: 55px;
      left: 45px;
    }
    &.client-2 {
      top: 0;
      left: 375px;
    }
    &.client-3 {
      top: 134px;
      left: 250px;
    }
    &.client-4 {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    &.client-5 {
      top: 100px;
      right: 276px;
    }
    &.client-6 {
      top: 182px;
      right: 45px;
    }
    &.client-7 {
      bottom: 175px;
      left: 0;
    }
    &.client-8 {
      bottom: 88px;
      left: 376px;
    }
    &.client-9 {
      bottom: 0;
      left: 123px;
    }
    &.client-10 {
      bottom: 170px;
      right: 233px;
    }
    &.client-11 {
      bottom: 89px;
      right: 0;
    }
    &.client-12 {
      bottom: 25px;
      right: 123px;
    }
  }
}

img {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  transition: filter linear 1s, transform 1s, opacity 1s;
  opacity: .25;
}

.unblur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: filter linear 1s, transform 3s, opacity 1s;
  transform: perspective(500px) translateZ(100px);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li class="client-1"><img class="unblur" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-2"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-3"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-4"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-5"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-6"><img class="unblur" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-7"><img class="unblur" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-8"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-9"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-10"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-11"><img class="unblur" src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
    <li class="client-12"><img src="https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder.com-logo1.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! you are my hero!